# Internet Explorer and Safari changes my CSS

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, safari

I am running Thesis 1.8.5 on Wordpress and here is my site www.texashomeloanpro.com . Because I am kind of new to this whole web-design thing, it just occurred to me to check my site in both Internet Explorer and Safari browsers. Unfortunately, my site looks horrible in both of these. More specifically, my homepage fonts are showing up too large, my homepage sidebars aren't positions correctly, and some of my rounded edges aren't showing up.

I know this is quite a laundry-list of CSS issues but if someone could just give me some general direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've tried this already, but a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) script usually does the trick for me.

It might break your webpage on the browser you are using, but the goal is to make the webpage look consistent across all browsers.

Comment: Uber, I looked at the link and, as you mentioned, it looks like it will break most of my CSS, which I would love to avoid if possible. Ideally, I need my site to look consistent across Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Internet Explorer. I originally built the site in Chrome and it looks correct on Safari at my home computer, but I just noticed the major inconsistencies show in Internet Explorer.

Comment: If you are not currently using a `reset.css`, and you did not examine your webpage in other browsers while you developed the site, then I suspect a reset script _will_ fix all of your inconsistencies. Unless you feel like going into each and every browser and fixing it manually, I'd suggest you add a reset.css and work in Chrome from there. Good luck!

Comment: uber, so my understanding is that I grab the code from the reset.css link that you provided, and paste it at the top of my customs folder (before all of my other CSS)? When I tried this, it had zero effect on my site when viewed in Chrome (which is awesome), and it had a mild improvement on my site in Internet Explorer. So at this point, how to I finish correcting all of the little inconsistencies that still exist across various browsers (i'm just looking for a little more direction)?

Comment: Gsifers, you've given a generic question that says, "my site is broken in some browsers. There's a  bunch of styling problems." The only answer I can give to that is something generic that fixes things across multiple browsers. If you have questions about specific issues on your page, please ask questions about those issues, specifically. I am not about to go through your website for you and figure out everything that is wrong with it. I don't think anyone is. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, Uber. My intention was to try and save you from having to go into much detail bc I assume you're crazy busy. Clearly the wrong approach in this situation.                                        Homepage issues in IE:                                                        1.PNG-both the red "Learn More" button and the headshot photos are displaced on the page and leave behind a strange white box where the photo should be.                                                     2.Rounded corners-my red "feature-box" below the header should have rounded corners at the top. 

Thanks,

G